# Animation for images to fly up from bottom of screen using VS blend

Tags: c#, animation, visual-studio-2012, storyboard, blend

I am creating an app that will allow the user to click on images and then they will transform into something else, and the code to do that is below:

```
 private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/smallImage.png")); 
            imageHolder.Source = bitmap;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Now the hard part is that I have to get these pre-transformed images to fly up onto the screen so the user can rush to click on them before they fall. I figured I would need to create storyboards and add those effects, if that is right word for it, but how exactly would I go about this in blend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to make fly out from another image in blend, I created individual storyboards for each image and recorded them flying around in whatever direction I wanted for as long as I needed. So for 3 seconds each and so on. Really easy once I got the hang of it, but hoping for new tutorials on blend for developers!